# ASP MVC non-breaking-space in Display attribute with DisplayNameFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, displayattribute

I have a model with a Property "Price" which has the DisplayAttribute

```
[Display(Name = "Price (in €)")]
```

Now i want to display this in a table header using

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
```

But when the column is very small, the Text might be broken into two Lines:

```
Price (in
€)
```

But i want it to break this way:

```
Price
(in €)
```

Is it possible to insert a non breaking space into the Display attribute?
Using "`Price (in&nbsp;€)`" results in the "`&nbsp;`" printed as Text.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Use Html.Raw(your string).

Comment: Non breaking space is a unicode character, with code 00a0. So this should work: `[Display(Name = "Price (in\u00a0€)")]`

Comment: Just don't use the attribute and write the markup in your view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Andrei posted the correct Answer in the comments:
Non breaking space is a unicode character, with code 00a0. So this should work:

```
[Display(Name = "Price (in\u00a0€)")]
```